# How to make a makefile reference another makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I have a project in C that has many different modules, and one makefile for everything.  What I would like to do is for each module to have its own makefile, and when that module is included in any project, that projects makefile can just reference the individual module's makefile.  That way anytime I have a project in which I want to use a certain module, I don't have to do a bunch of editing to my project makefile.

Any help you can offer on this would be appreciated.

Comment: `include /path/to/another/makefile`

Comment: You'll have to start using absolute paths, not relative. And I'd be more confident that we'd answered your question if you gave a simple example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using GNU Make utility, then my answer could be of some help to you. Recently, I was reading `GNU Make Manual` for my own project.

The `include` directive tells `make` to suspend reading the current makefile and read one or more other makefiles before continuing. The directive is a line in the makefile that looks like this:

```
include filenames
```

If you want make to simply ignore a makefile which does not exist or cannot be remade, with no error message, use the -include directive instead of include, like this:

```
-include filenames
```

However, there is another way which is variable `MAKEFILES`. If the environment variable `MAKEFILES` is defined, make considers its value as a list of names (separated by whitespace) of additional makefiles to be read before the others.

You can refer [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) for more information.

Comment: I have a lot to learn yet about makefiles, but this information is helpful.  Thanks also for the link!

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and mark my answer as best answer if it helped!

Comment: got it. I'm new to this site, so my upvotes don't count yet unfortunately.